# Read from file and write to cout in one line

Tags: c++, file-handling

Is there any way I can perform both these actions in one line:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);
std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
```

i.e., I am looking for something like:
    `std::cout<<fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);<<std::endl;`

Obviously `&n` has to be replaced. `FILE*` has to be used though.

Comment: If you changed your code to use a `std::istream` instead of a `FILE*`, you could use `cout << in.rdbuf()` IIRC

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line?

Comment: @Galik Fair point. Code golf? What the compiler emits in the end might be fairly the same like the _inline variant_.

Comment: @Galik There really isn't a reason why. Just looking for some uncommon syntax:). I suppose practically I could always keep it 2 lines. Apologies if this was the wrong site to ask.

Comment: _@leo_ Don't worry, your question is just fine. I can imagine use cases, no matter what @Galik says.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Of course, it can be important to save precious bytes on the hard disk. All those line-endings in the source code add up! ;-)

Comment: @Galik I more tought about how to inject functions that don't follow the signature `ostream& foo(ostream &, T&)` into a bigger output formatting sequence, when you want to output T after manipulation it somehow. Readability of such code matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do the `fscanf()` call inline using the `,` operator:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::cout<< (fscanf(stdin,"%d",&n),n)<<std::endl;
}
```

See a live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c59ddc328fbbc2f7).

---

For the present example there aren't many good use cases, but I can think at least this one to save formatting readability:

Say you have a type `T`, providing an operation like `void T::update();` and you're too lazy to wrap calls to `T::update()` into something like `std::ostream& update(ostream&,T&)` you can use this trick:

```
std::array<std::array<T,4>,4> m { // A matrix of T
    { T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() } ,
    { T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() } ,
    { T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() } ,
    { T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() ,T::create() }
};

// ....

using u = T::update;
std::cout << "Current matrix state:\n" <<
(m[0][0].u(),m[0][0]) << ',' (m[0][1].u(),m[0][1]) << ',' (m[0][2].u(),m[0][2]) << ',' (m[0][3].u(),m[0][3]) << '\n' <<
(m[1][0].u(),m[1][0]) << ',' (m[1][1].u(),m[1][1]) << ',' (m[1][2].u(),m[1][2]) << ',' (m[1][3].u(),m[1][3]) << '\n' <<
(m[2][0].u(),m[2][0]) << ',' (m[2][1].u(),m[2][1]) << ',' (m[2][2].u(),m[2][2]) << ',' (m[2][3].u(),m[2][3]) << '\n' <<
(m[3][0].u(),m[3][0]) << ',' (m[3][1].u(),m[3][1]) << ',' (m[3][2].u(),m[3][2]) << ',' (m[3][3].u(),m[3][3]) << '\n' <<
flush;
```